# Why this leads to a contradiction in the set of cantor?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

\begin{array}[lll]
&&A_0 &= \left[0,1\right] \\[1ex]
&A_1 &= \left[0,\frac13\right] \cup \left[\frac23,1\right] \\[1ex]
&A_2 &= \left[0, \frac19\right] \cup\left[\frac29,\frac13\right] \cup \left[\frac23,\frac79\right]\cup\left[ \frac89,1\right]\\
&\cdots\\
&C &= \text{set of Cantor} = \bigcap A_i
\end{array}

The following property is valid for the Cantor set

$$A_{k-j} \subset 3^{j}A_{k} $$

I want to show that no element of the Cantor set can have the algarimo "$1$" in its representation in base $3$, so I'll assume there is an element in the set that has that number.

Let $$x \in C  ,\quad x= \frac{a_{0}}{3} +\frac{a_1}{3^2} + \cdots$$

If $ x $ has a "$1$" in its base $3$ representation, then:

$$3^{m}x = a+ \frac{1}{3}+\frac{a_{m+1}}{3^2} +\cdots = a+y,\quad a \in \mathbb{N} ,\ y \in A_1$$

Note that

$$1/3 \leq y \leq 2/3 $$

I just need to ensure that $y$ cannot be $1/3$ or $2/3$.

If $y=\frac{1}{3}  \implies a_{m+1}=a_{m+2}\cdots = 0$

Why can not this happen?
How to enter into contradiction by assuming $y = 1/3$?

Answer (score 4):

The correct statement is that $x \in C$ if and only if **there exists** a base 3 representation $x = .a_1 a_2 a_3 \ldots$ such that $a_i \in \{0,2\}$ for all $i$. So, for example, $\frac{1}{3}$ is indeed in $C$, because
$$\frac{1}{3} = .1000000000\ldots = .022222222\ldots \in C
$$
As you can see, just as repeating $9$'s in base 10 lead to non-uniqueness of decimal representation, repeating $2$'s in base 3 also lead to non-uniqueness of trinary representation.

More generally, for numbers $\frac{1}{3} < y < \frac{2}{3}$ the trinary representation always has a $1$ and none of those numbers is in $C$, but if $y=\frac{1}{3}$ or if $y=\frac{2}{3}$ **one of** the two trinary representatives of $y$ has no $1$, so both of $\frac{1}{3}$ and $\frac{2}{3}$ are in $C$.

Comment: But if y = 1/3 or 2/3 then x is an element of the marcus set that can be represented in base 3 with some number "1", and this is false, because y = 1/3 or 2/3 can not happen

Comment: I do not know what you mean by the "marcus set", which is not mentioned in your question. I am also unsure what you mean by the statement "$y = \frac{1}{3}$ or $\frac{2}{3}$" cannot happen". As said, $\frac{1}{3}$ and $\frac{2}{3}$ are both elements of the Cantor set, both have a trinary representation without the number $1$. Both of them also have a trinary representation *with* a $1$, but as said membership in the Cantor set is determined by *existence of* a trinary representation without a $1$.